# Tensorflow : Creating a loop for embedded feaure column for DNN Classifier

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to fit in DNN Classifier in tensorflow. I have multiple embedded feature columns in TensorFlow and I am trying to create the loop to avoid manual typing to create feature column but its not working. Below is the code which I tried but its returning an error while trying to fit as feature columns.

```
for col in df_col:
    if df[col].dtypes == 'object':
        feat_cols.append(
            tf.feature_column.embedding_column(
                tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(
                   col,
                   hash_bucket_size=len(df[col].unique())
                ),
                dimension=len(df[col].unique()))
        )
    else:
        feat_cols.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(col))
```

Answer (score 0):

DNN classifier on tensorflow require little different approach. Check the code below; it is self explanatory.

```
from pandas.api.types import is_string_dtype
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype

my_columns = []

for col in df.columns:
    if is_string_dtype(diabetes[col]): #is_string_dtype is pandas function
        ccol=tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(col,
                                        hash_bucket_size= len(df[col].unique()))
        my_columns.append(tf.feature_column.embedding_column(ccol, dimension=len(df[col].unique())))

    elif is_numeric_dtype(df[col]): #is_numeric_dtype is pandas function
        my_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(col))
```